# `bundle install` on Docker: fails because 'deployment mode'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

Running normal `bundle install` on a Rails container.

Met with..

```
You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

If this is a development machine, remove the /application/Gemfile freeze 
by running `bundle config unset deployment`.

The dependencies in your gemfile changed

You have added to the Gemfile:
* webpacker (~> 5.1.1)

You have deleted from the Gemfile:
* webpacker (~> 4.x)
```

Without having to delete the `Gemfile.lock`, how to bundle on Docker and avoid this?

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you figure this out in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `RUN bundle config --global frozen 1` in your Dockerfile you'll need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Are your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock files stored on your host and copied into your container at build time? If so, you can try updating your lock file by running a bundle lock update in the same directory using another container:

```
  docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app ruby:2.7.5 bundle lock --update
```

That will create a ruby container using the default image and then update the Gemfile.lock file. That worked to update the Gem for me and I was subsequently able to build the actual container I was working with.